# Describing a place that is not very busy

Tags: grammar

How would you describe a place, a dorm to be more specific, that's not very crowded?

> At dorm X there is not a lot of people who live there ( this is my wild guess )

Comment: "Not very busy" and "not very crowded" and "not many people living there" are all different concepts. Which is it that you are thinking of?

Comment: In relation to a dorm, "uncrowded" would probably do, but in practice it's more likely you'd say it was "quiet".

Comment: I dont understand why this question was closed. The question clearly explains what is being asked. Closing it for proper reasons wouldn't be an issue, but closing it and randomly selecting something from the list doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @Robusto - Why did you vote to close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If few people live somewhere, you might say that it's *sparsely populated*.

Comment: For a geographical area I would use sparsely populated, however I would not consider it to describe a singular room. When discussing the occupancy of a room I would use the empty - full scale so would describe it as almost empty.

Comment: @JoeTaylor: You're quite right. I hadn't appeciated what a 'dorm' was. The OP should take away his acceptance of my answer, but it may not be possible now the question is closed.